# check if the inserted data is already present in database

Tags: magento-1

Last time I got help from this site how to save data in database. This is my form.

```
<form role="form" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('test/user_view/save'); ?>" method="post">
 <div id="form_div">
  <label id="test_id_label">Test_Id</label>
  <input id="test_id" type="text" name="test_id" />
  <br /><br />
  <label>Title</label>
  <input id="title" type="text" name="title" />
  <br /><br />
  <label>File Name</label>
  <input id="file_name" type="text" name="filename" />
  <br /><br />
  <label>Content</label>
  <input id="content" type="text" name="content" />
  <br /><br />
  <label>Status</label>
  <input id="status" type="text" name="status" />
  <br /><br />
  <input id="add_button" type="submit" value="Add" />
 </div>
 <br /><br />
</form>
```

and the given below code is in controller for save operation:

```
public function SaveAction() {
   $postdata = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
   if($postdata)
   {
       $model = Mage::getModel("test/test");
       $model->setData($postdata);
       $model->setCreatedTime(strtotime('now'));
       $model->save();
       $this->_redirect('test/user_view/history');
   }
}
```

With the help of this code my data gets saved and new row gets created. However now what I want is if user enters the same id and save data it must overwrite the row, and if not then a new row gets added at the bottom with test_id auto incremented. I took test_id auto increment in database. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: provide primary key of table or make test_id as primary key

Comment: Can u please explain in brief, I am new in magento

Comment: can you share the code of your script which create table for your custom extension.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function SaveAction() {
   $postdata = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
   if($postdata)
   {
       $model = Mage::getModel("test/test");
       $model->load($postdata["test_id"],"test_id");
       $model->setData($postdata);
       $model->setCreatedTime(strtotime('now'));
       $model->save();
       $this->_redirect('test/user_view/history');
   }
}
```

Load a record with `test_id` if available and then update it.